# jQuery click event lost after appenTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using appendTo to move list items between two list, upon a button click. The button resides in each `li` element. Each `li` has two buttons, of which only one is visible at a time, depending on the list the li currently resides.

Here is the function:

```
// 'this' is the first list
// Click Handler for remove and add buttons
$(this.selector + ', ' + settings.target + ' li button').click(function(e) {

    var button = $(e.target);
    var listItem = button.parent('li');

    listItem.children("button").toggleClass("hidden");

    if (button.hasClass("assign")) {
        // Add Element to assignment list
        listItem.appendTo(settings.target);
    }
    else
        if (button.hasClass("remove")) {
            // Remove Element from assignment list
            listItem.appendTo(source);
        }
})
```

As long as the list item reside in the original li, the click events in the buttons are triggered. However, once it is moved to the other list using `listItem.apendTo`. The click item no longer fires. Why is this the case? I cant find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle?

Comment: What you are looking for is cloning:

.clone( true ) does the trick.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: You should probably look into delegates http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: A delegate did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by user 'apsdehal', a deleate was what i needed:

```
// Click Handler for remove and add buttons
    $(source.selector + ', ' + settings.target ).delegate("li button", "click", function(e) {

        var button = $(e.target);
        var listItem = button.parent('li');

        listItem.children("button").toggleClass("hidden");

        if (button.hasClass("assign")) {
            // Add Element to assignment list
            listItem.appendTo(settings.target);
        }
        else
        if (button.hasClass("remove")) {
            // Remove Element from assignment list
            listItem.appendTo(source);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes jQuery won't be able to find something if it isn't present in the DOM when your script first loads. If it is a dynamically created element, try replacing your click event handlers with ['on'](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Rather than:

```
$(".aClass").click(function(){
    // Code here
})
```

Try:

```
$("body").on("click", ".aClass", function(){
    Code here
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Delegated event handling really should use a parent object as close as possible to the dynamic element, not something as far away as `body` or `document`.  In fact, `.live()` was removed from jQuery because it put everything on the `document` object and that can cause performance issues.

Comment: Well the click events works, it just wont work after i moved the encapsulating li to another list.

Comment: Is your selector correct once it is outside the list? What are the values of `settings.target`, what does your DOM look like? What is `source`? Add a jsfiddle and maybe someone can help in more detail

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on` event.

```
$(".aClass").on("click",  function(){
    //Your custom code
})
```

`on` event is usful for Dynamically generated data + static data already in HTML.